# Databases Views with Parameters

Tags: sql, db2

I know that is it possible to create a View with Parameters at MSSQL, does anyone knows if I can achieve something similar with a DB2 database?

I have a more complicated query which includes a user number which I want to pass as param to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server supports table-valued functions.  If a table-valued function is "inline" (i.e. a single statement and not a multi-statement TVF with a BEGIN END), then it effectively acts as a parameterized view and can be optimized similarly to views.

DB2 supports a [table-valued function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0003493.htm) feature with very similar capabilities `CREATE FUNCTION RETURNS TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a stored procedure.
Views have no parameters as far as I'm informed.